# Rails + Vue Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js

Even though rails 6 is still in beta I thought to test it out building a rails + vue app but when trying to parse the json data im getting a error in the console "VM353:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0" Not sure why my data is not being parsed. Undefined but cant figure out why

Here is my hello_vue.js file

```
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.esm'
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'

Vue.use(VueResource)



     document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
          Vue.http.headers.common['X-CSRF-Token'] = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content')

          var element = document.getElementById("gameapp-form") 
          if(element != null) {

              var game_application = JSON.parse(element.dataset.game_application)

              var app = new Vue({
                el: element,
                data: function () {
                    return { game_application: game_application}
                }, 
                methods: {
                    saveApplication: function() {
                        this.$http.post('/game_applications', {game_application: this.game_application }).then(response => {
                            console.log(response)
                        }, response => {
                            console.log(response)
                        })
                    }
                }
              })

            }
        }

    )
```

Here is my _form.html.erb file

```
<%= content_tag :div,
  id: "gameapp-form",
  data: {
    game_application: game_application.to_json(except: [:created_at, :updated_at]),
  } do %>

  <label>Game Name</label>
  <input type="text" v-model="game_application.name" />

  <label>Game Name</label>
  <input type="text" v-model="game_application.video_link" />

  <button v-on:click="saveApplication">Send Application</button>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `response.data` with your axios request

```
this.$http.post('/game_applications', {game_application: this.game_application})
          .then(response => response.data)
          .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
          })
```

Axios returns your JSON output in the `data` field. So, in the first `then` we are basically returning `response.data` so that you can use it in the next `then`. Hope that makes sense.